# Knowing all that you know about SQL and no-SQL, what's best to store trees?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, nosql

We're about to upgrade commenting system on our web site, which right now is a single-level structure and is using MySQL. We want change it to multi-level.

One thing to keep in mind is that we show all comments under each user profile.

So far considerations are as follows:

**SQL pros:**

- Easier to retrieve comments for each user

**SQL cons:**

- Takes longer to retrieve entire tree for the thread

**no-SQL pros:**

- All comments in a thread can be retrieved as a single object
- Existing tree patterns

**no-SQL cons:**

- Harder / slower to retrieve comments of just one user
- More difficult updates to existing trees

What are other pros and cons, in your production experience?

Comment: By multi-level do you mean threaded comments, e.g. users can reply to each other's comments and they are indented or something in the display?

Comment: Since MySQL does not support [recursive CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), you'd have to do something along the lines of [what's discussed here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7147/2660) to quickly retrieve a comment and all its children.

Comment: Chris, exactly, I mean nested / threaded comments

Answer (score 1):

With RDBMS you can use JOINs - so store each comment just once, no data duplication (pro), and can fulfil both your display use cases by utilising JOINs.

With e.g. MongoDB, JOINs aren't supported (con), but you could achieve good performance for both cases by duplicating the data - store a comment once in the page document it relates to in the tree structure and once again in a "UserComments" collection document that relates to that specific user. i.e. to see all the comments associated with a page, query CollectionA for that page, to view all the comments for a user, query CollectionB by user id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tree based structure in SQL, see LTree for PostgreSQL - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ltree.html

On top of this, you can perform recursive queries using common table expressions like Disqus does - http://justcramer.com/2010/05/30/scaling-threaded-comments-on-django-at-disqus/

Comment: That Disqus article is great, thanks. We're actually looking at Disqus as the feature benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store all comments in a thread in a single record with SQL by storing it as an XML string. This would give you the easiness of access combined with fast retrieval.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue of fast retrieval of all user's comments

Comment: Yes, I see, forgot that part.

Answer (score 0):

for NOSQL (& can apply to SQL too), you do not have to store the data in a normalised form, denormalise it. store comments in two places! have a list of comments on the user.

some good reading from kyle banker on [nested comment approaches](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails#MongoDBDataModelingandRails-Nested,EmbeddedComments).

and a similiar [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262669/nested-comments-in-mongodb)